# Wrap typeahead suggestions in a table

Tags: typeahead.js

I'm trying to get my typeahead autocomplete to return its results inside of a table. Because each suggestion is rendered individually there is nowhere to include the table tag without it getting rendered for each suggestion.

I tried using the header/footer templating by putting an open table tag in the header and a close table tag in the footer but the suggestions don't get rendered into the table.

```
$('#orgSelector').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'orgSelector',
  source: orgSelector,
  display: 'name',
  limit: 20,
  templates:{
    empty: "<div>No matches</div>",
    header: Handlebars.compile("<table class='table injected-table'><tbody>"),
    suggestion: function (d){ return '<tr><td>' + d.name + '</tr></td>' },
    footer: Handlebars.compile("</tbody></table>")
  }
});
```

Returns:

```
<div class="tt-dataset tt-dataset-orgSelector">
<table class="table injected-table">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Hardware </td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Pharmacy</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Guns</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Marine</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Firearms</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Automotive</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Outfitters</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Sales</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Enterprises</td>
    </tr><tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Farms</td></tr>
</div>
    </div>
```

Need it to return:

```
<div class="tt-dataset tt-dataset-orgSelector">
<table class="table injected-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Hardware </td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Pharmacy</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Guns</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Marine</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Firearms</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Automotive</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Outfitters</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Sales</td></tr>
    <tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Enterprises</td>
    </tr><tr class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><td>D &amp; D Farms</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Same problem with <ul>. Cannot render suggestions as a list.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work, but not with "automatic column width":
[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var Policies = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('ReferenceNo','QuoteName'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote:
    {
      url: '/AACOAgentPortal/LightningNav/Policies/%QUERY',
      wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
  });

  // Initializing the typeahead
  $('#Policies').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'Policies',
    display: 'ReferenceNo',
    source: Policies,
    templates:
    {
      empty: [
        '<div class="empty-message">',
        'Unable to find any Policies that match the current query',
        '</div>'
      ].join('\n'),
      header: function(data) {
        return '<table><tr>' + '<th nowrap style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;padding:0px 3px;min-width:250px;">ReferenceNo</th>'+'<th nowrap style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;padding:0px 3px;min-width:250px;">QuoteName</th>' + '</tr></table>';
      },
      suggestion: function(data) {
        return '<table><tr>' + '<td nowrap style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;padding:0px 3px;min-width:250px;">' + data.ReferenceNo + '</td>'+'<td nowrap style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;padding:0px 3px;min-width:250px;">' + data.QuoteName + '</td>' + '</tr></table>';
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fighting to do something typeahead doesn't intend it was easier and perhaps more elegant to emulate a table using the css `display: table;` property.

There is a good article on the subject [here.](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout)

Comment: You still need to find a way to combine and wrap what's returned for each record from the **suggestion** function in an element (a *div* for your answer).

Answer (score 0):

**This would fix the width issue:**

```
header: function() {
    return (
        '<table class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"><tr>' +
        '<th nowrap style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;padding:0px 3px;min-width:250px;">ReferenceNo</th>' +
        '<th nowrap style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;padding:0px 3px;min-width:250px;">QuoteName</th>' +
        '</tr></table>'
    );
},
```